# Как заменить функцию конструктор на класс с закрытыми полями?

Tags: javascript

Нужно решить задачку. Условия следующие:

> Замените функцию конструктор на класс. Все свойства класса Car поменяйте на закрытые поля и для каждого поля добавьте getter и setter по необходимости. Для поля html предусмотрите возможность только получения значения, организуйте код таким образом, чтобы не допустить редактирование значения свойства html напрямую.

Ниже приведена функция конструктор и то как сделал я. В моем варианте выдает вот такое в консоль

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#html' must be declared in an enclosing class

Возможно из-за закрытых полей у меня проблема с доступом. В общем надеюсь на подсказку где я проморгал. Спасибо.

```
function Car(image, manufacturer) {
            this.image = image;
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.html = `<img src="images/${this.image}" /><br />Производитель: ${this.manufacturer}<br />`;
        }

        let car1 = new Car("audi-a6-250.jpg", "Audi");
        let car2 = new Car("jaguar-x-type-250.jpg", "Jaguar");
        let car3 = new Car("porsche-carrera-911-250.jpg", "Porsce");

        let placeholder1 = document.querySelector("#placeholder1");
        let placeholder2 = document.querySelector("#placeholder2");
        let placeholder3 = document.querySelector("#placeholder3");

        placeholder1.innerHTML = car1.html;
        placeholder2.innerHTML = car2.html;
        placeholder3.innerHTML = car3.html; 

    /*     <-------Мой вариант--------> */
        class Car {
            #image;
            #manufacture;

            constructor(image, manufacture, html) {
                this.#image = image;
                this.#manufacture = manufacture;
                this.#html = `<img src="images/${this.#image}" /><br />Производитель: ${this.#manufacturer}<br />`;
                             
            }

            set html (value) {
                if (value = "") {
                    alert('Ошибка')
                } else {
                    this.#html = value
                }
            }

            get html () {
                if (this.#html === undefined) {
                    this.#html = 0;
                }
                return this.#html;
            }

        }
        
        let car1 = new Car("audi-a6-250.jpg", "Audi");
        let car2 = new Car("jaguar-x-type-250.jpg", "Jaguar");
        let car3 = new Car("porsche-carrera-911-250.jpg", "Porsce");

        let placeholder1 = document.querySelector("#placeholder1");
        let placeholder2 = document.querySelector("#placeholder2");
        let placeholder3 = document.querySelector("#placeholder3");

        placeholder1.innerHTML = car1.html;
        placeholder2.innerHTML = car2.html;
        placeholder3.innerHTML = car3.html;
```

Comment: Вот вы присваиваете значения трём закрытым полям, а объявили всего два...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#html' must be declared in an
> enclosing class

Перевод:

> частное поле '#html' должно быть объявлено во включающем классе

Вы не объявили приватную переменную #html

```js
class Car {
  #image = null;
  #manufacture = null;
  #html = null;

  constructor(image, manufacture, html) {
    this.#image = image;
    this.#manufacture = manufacture;
    this.#html = `<img src="images/${this.#image}" /><br />Производитель: ${this.#manufacture}<br />`;
  }

  set html(value) {
    if (value === "") {
      throw new Error('Ошибка, html не может быть равен пустой строке');
    } else {
      this.#html = value;
    }
  }

  get html() {
    return this.#html;
  }

}

let car1 = new Car("audi-a6-250.jpg", "Audi");
let car2 = new Car("jaguar-x-type-250.jpg", "Jaguar");
let car3 = new Car("porsche-carrera-911-250.jpg", "Porsce");

let placeholder1 = document.querySelector("#placeholder1");
let placeholder2 = document.querySelector("#placeholder2");
let placeholder3 = document.querySelector("#placeholder3");

placeholder1.innerHTML = car1.html;
placeholder2.innerHTML = car2.html;
placeholder3.innerHTML = car3.html;
```

```html
<div id="placeholder1">placeholder1</div>
<div id="placeholder2">placeholder2</div>
<div id="placeholder3">placeholder3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но возможно ошибка из-за нейминга полей с решеткой. Это новшество, которое еще поддерживают не все движки, нужен полифил. Раньше защищенные свойства начинались с `_`, но они конечно же попадут в дочерние классы. Подробнее вот здесь можете почитать, тут всё описано https://learn.javascript.ru/private-protected-properties-methods

```
const placeholder1 = document.querySelector('#placeholder1');
const placeholder2 = document.querySelector('#placeholder2');
const placeholder3 = document.querySelector('#placeholder3');

class Car {
    _image;
    _manufacturer;
    _html;

    constructor(image, manufacturer) {
        this._image = image;
        this._manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this._html = `<img src="images/${this._image}" /><br />Производитель: ${this._manufacturer}<br />`;
    }

    set html(val) {
        throw new Error("You can't edit private fields");
    }
    get html() {
        return this._html;
    }
}

const car1 = new Car('audi-a6-250.jpg', 'Audi');
const car2 = new Car('jaguar-x-type-250.jpg', 'Jaguar');
const car3 = new Car('porsche-carrera-911-250.jpg', 'Porsce');

placeholder1.innerHTML = car1.html;
placeholder2.innerHTML = car2.html;
placeholder3.innerHTML = car3.html;
```

Вариант с новым синтаксисом

```
const placeholder1 = document.querySelector('#placeholder1');
const placeholder2 = document.querySelector('#placeholder2');
const placeholder3 = document.querySelector('#placeholder3');

class Car {
    #image;
    #manufacturer;
    #html;

    constructor(image, manufacturer) {
        this.#image = image;
        this.#manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.#html = `<img src="images/${this.#image}" /><br />Производитель: ${
            this.#manufacturer
        }<br />`;
    }

    set html(val) {
        throw new Error("You can't edit private fields");
    }
    get html() {
        return this.#html;
    }
}

const car1 = new Car('audi-a6-250.jpg', 'Audi');
const car2 = new Car('jaguar-x-type-250.jpg', 'Jaguar');
const car3 = new Car('porsche-carrera-911-250.jpg', 'Porsce');

placeholder1.innerHTML = car1.html;
placeholder2.innerHTML = car2.html;
placeholder3.innerHTML = car3.html;
```